# How to .then chain but need the resolve() value from the previous promise - javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, chaining, method-chaining

The issue lies in the "backendLoginCheck" function. I want to .then() chain "ifUserIsDisabled" after "getUserByEmail". But I need the "userRecord" from getUserByEmail for the input into "ifUserIsDisabled".

I also want both functions to share the same .catch in "backendLoginCheck" function.

**Current Code:**

```
function getUserByEmail(email){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        firebase.serverAuthAdmin147th.getUserByEmail(email)
            .then(function(userRecord) {
                resolve(userRecord);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                reject({token: null, errorCode: "auth/user-not-found"});
            });
    })
}

function ifUserIsDisabled(userRecord){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(!userRecord.disabled){
            resolve();
        }
        else{
            reject({token: null, errorCode: "auth/user-disabled"});
        }
    })
}

function backendLoginCheck(email, password, callback){
    var token = null;
    var errorCode = null;
    var uid = null;
    getUserByEmail(email)
        .then(function(userRecord){
            ifUserIsDisabled(userRecord);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            callback(error);
        });
}
```

**Desired Idea:**

```
...
getUserByEmail(email)
    .then(ifUserIsDisabled(userRecord))
    .then(nextFunction())
    .then(nextFunction2(uses_resolveVal_from_nextFunction))
    .then(nextFunctionEtc())
    .catch(function(error){
        callback(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it looks like you're almost there. If a then chain in a promise *returns another promise* you can pass the resolved values down the chain

for example:

```
function firstFunction() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if (someError) {
           reject(firstErr)
       } else {
           resolve('first value')
       }
   })
} 

function secondFunction() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if (someError) {
           reject(secondErr)
       } else {
           resolve('second value')
       }
   })
} 

firstFunction()
  .then((resolvedFirstValue) => {
      return secondFunction()
  })
  .then((resolvedSecondValue) => {
      console.log(resolvedSecondValue)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      // any error in the entire chain
      console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: Perfect this was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize it was as simple as "return"

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

should be like this:

```
getUserByEmail(email)
.then(function(userRecord){
  return ifUserIsDisabled(userRecord);
})
.then(nextFunction())
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. I have that already in the "Current Code". I want ifUserIsDisabled reject to also use the .catch in backendLoginCheck

Comment: if you `return` the `ifUserIsDisabled` it should bubble up to the `catch` in question.

Comment: Oops missed the `return`.